# Issues with creating an address locator using multi-point features in Arcmap/catalog 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, multipart, arcgis-10.4, multipoint

The error I get when trying to create this locator is *"000042: Failed to create the address locator* which states that I must -

1. have permission to write to the disk/database
2. have enough disk space
3. have a valid connection
4. have valid geocoding rule files
5. have valid address locator style

I have write permissions, I have enough disk space (1+ tb), and I do not require a connection which leaves #4 and #5 as possible reasons why it fails.

I am trying to use the gazetteer locator style as each of the features represent a geographic place, and a multi-point feature (which I suspect is the reason for the error).

So in short, does Arcmap/catalog 10.4 have issues with creating an address locator using multi-point features? Is there a work around for this? Is the gazetteer locator style the wrong style to use in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost certain that multipoint geometry is not supported in geocoding, as that defeats the purpose of geocoding. From the [ArcGIS help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/commonly-used-address-locator-styles.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_81054CF66AF8437A9E90CA580CE8496F):

> General—Gazetteer
>
> The General—Gazetteer address locator style lets you create locators
>   for data that contains the gazetteer names. A gazetteer is a
>   geographical dictionary or directory for place-names. You can use
>   address locators created with this style to find features like
>   mountains, bridges, rivers, cities, etc.
>
> This locator style uses feature classes with point or polygon geometry
>   as reference data. In addition to a feature ID field and SHAPE field,
>   feature classes that you can use as reference data for the locator
>   must have attributes representing the names and geographical zones
>   such as city, state, country to distinguish the location of the
>   feature.

You can try converting any multipoint features into convex polygons that cover those features, or deaggregating into individual points.

Comment: I was able to work around my problem by deaggregating my data into individual points .